# How to assign a value in java?

Tags: java

I want to build my own class similar to a String class that I can use like this,

MyClass mc="testvalue";

I am confused at how to do this, where would "testvalue" be assigned to?

Thanks.

Comment: the question is unclear.

Comment: you will have to define better what are you trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MyClass mc="testvalue";
```

This is not possible, no matter what MyClass is.
`"testvalue"` is a String literal, and String is a final class (can't be extended). Hence the above construct can't compile in Java.

Comment: Not to mention there is no operator overloading in Java.

Comment: though String is indeed final, this only matters for the exact oposite String str = new MyClass(); will never work because String is final. MyClass mc = "testvalue"; will never work because String does not inherit from MyClass. it would work for Object obj = "testvalue";

Comment: Ok, so I forgot to say "so MyClass can't extend String". Sue me, but I thought that was obvious

Comment: @Sean: this is not the point. the point is your answer gives solution for "why can't I use String variable to store MyClass object" and not "why can't I use MyClass variable to store a String object?" after all, you can use: Object obj = "asdf"; although String is final. it has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @amit sigh. I know. the point is that we all know that String does not have any super classes except Object

Comment: @Sean: I could not understand from your last comment if you agree/disagree with my comment that (in other words): "the fact that the command from the question will not compile is not connected to String being final"

Comment: @amit yes and no: I mean we know that MyClass can't be a Superclass of String because you can't introduce superclasses to an existing hierarchy in Java, so it must be a subclass, which it can't be since String is final. And yes, even if it were a subclass, one would have to rewrite the compiler to actually instantiate the subclass from the `MyClass mc = "testvalue"` code.

Answer (score 2):

The common way of storing values in a class in Java is to create a class with member-variables and read/write from/to them using get/set methods:

```
class YourClass{
  private String value;

  public YourClass(String value){
    // Constructor
    this.value = value;
  }

  public String getValue(){
    return value;
  }

  public void setValue(String new_value){
    this.value = new_value;
  }

}
```

So you can do something like this:

```
YourClass yc = new YourClass("Your Value");
yc.getValue(); // Returns your Value
vc.setValue("A new Value"); // Sets your Value
```

Comment: I think you mean *member* variables, not *global* variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
MyClass mc="testvalue";
```

here value is `"testvalue"` which is string and you are trying to assign it to a reference variable. which isn't allowed,`mc` is assumed to hold a reference to an Object of `MyClass` (or its subtype)

You can assign it to `String`'s reference, for example

```
String  str ="testValue";
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Java supports neither implicit conversions nor operator overloading, you would need to implement either a constructor or a static factory method that takes the string.

You could also go the pre-processor route to create a language variant, but that's whole other ballgame.